# fetch data from core as an Model object

Tags: swift, core-data

So I have an App that it purpose is to parse a json, save it to coreData, load it back from coreData and present it in a collectionView.

My problem is the type of data I'm getting back dosent match for my Model.
I will try to explain in shot:

I made a model named Movie which is Decodable. I parse the Json an before I start saving it to the core I putting it in an arrayList

```
var movieList : [Movie] = [Movie]()
```

which used to fill the collectionView at first.

the saving isnt hard as well as I create an object of the entity type I created named Film and I save it to the core.

the problem is when I fetch all the data back I use a completion to transfer the array with is an array of type Film, the problem is I cant do this:

```
 self.movieList = fetchedArray
```

because its [Film] and not [Movie]

theoretically I know they may be couple of solutions I just dont know what to do exactly.

I also managed to get back an array of [Any] but again, I dont know what to do with it .

any suggestions ? hope I was clear enough

Comment: What is the difference between `Film` and `Movie`? Why are you saving as `Film` if you want the objects to be a `Movie` later? Does `Film` inherit from `Movie` (or vice-versa)?

Comment: If you have `Film `for persistence but want to work with `Movie` in the app then why not just add a `toMovie() -> Movie` func to Film or a constructor in `Movie` that takes a `Film` object as parameter and call it directly after the fetch has been executed?